# np.load() in generator slows down drastically after a number of iterations

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, generator

I am training a large dataset with Keras. I have about 500 000 npy-files (2x 240000) that are loaded batch-wise with a data generator. During training the GPU utilization is high in the very beginning, then it stabilizes at 0%, sometimes spiking up to 20-30%.

When testing the generator in a for-loop, it shows the same tendency. It
works perfectly for a short time in the beginning, then it suddenly slows down considerably (approx. 100 times as slow).

I have narrowed it down to the np.load(). As suggested in other relevant posts, I have tried gc.collect(), and opening and closing the file for each load. None of these solved the problem.

I would like to avoid rebuilding the dataset.

Quite new to this. Does anyone have suggestions for how to improve the performance of the data generator?

The data generator:

```
def data_generator(train = True, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, dim_x=(300,69), dim_y=(300,66)):
    if train: 
        filenames = x_train_fn
    else: 
        filenames = x_val_fn
    batch_i = 0
    while True:
        if batch_i >= (len(filenames)// batch_size):  
            batch_i = 0
            np.random.shuffle(filenames)

        file_chunk = filenames[batch_i*batch_size:(batch_i+1)*batch_size]
        X = np.zeros((batch_size,*dim_x))
        y = np.zeros((batch_size,*dim_y))
        
        for i, ID in enumerate(file_chunk): 
            X[i,] = np.load(data_dir_x + ID)
            y[i,] = np.load(data_dir_y + ID.replace("x", "y"))

        yield X, y
        batch_i += 1  

    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: data_generator(train=True),(tf.float32, tf.float32))
    validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: data_generator(train=False), (tf.float32, tf.float32))

    train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    validation_dataset = validation_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

The model used for training:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Input(shape=(SEQ_LEN,INPUT_DIMS)))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(HIDDEN_UNITS1, return_sequences=True, dropout=d, name= 'lstm1'))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(HIDDEN_UNITS2, return_sequences=True, dropout=d,name= 'lstm2'))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(HIDDEN_UNITS3, return_sequences=True, dropout=d, name= 'lstm3'))
model.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(mdn.MDN(OUTPUT_DIMS, N_MIXES, name='mdn_outputs'),name='td_mdn'))
 
model.compile(loss=mdn.get_mixture_loss_func(OUTPUT_DIMS,N_MIXES), optimizer=opt)

model.summary()

model.fit(train_dataset,
          steps_per_epoch = int(num_train_ex // BATCH_SIZE),
          epochs = EPOCHS,
          verbose = 1,
          validation_data = validation_dataset,
          validation_steps = int(num_val_ex// BATCH_SIZE),
          callbacks=callbacks, use_multiprocessing=True, workers=8)
```

Have been using this for-loop for testing the generator:

```
dataset_check = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: data_generator(train=True), (tf.float32, tf.float32))

for x, y in dataset_check.take(1000):
    print('ok')
```

Comment: How large are the files you're loading?  Your memory is not infinite.  Once you've loaded more than your RAM (8GB? 16GB?), then the system has to start swapping your memory out to disk to make room for new data.  That takes time.

Comment: Take a look at performance tips on [Tensorflow Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/performances#large_datasets). Thanks!